# Store text of driver.find_element into a python variable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to create an discord embed that containts info of some webstite. Im trying to store the driver.find_element.text of with selenium.

Then I want to put that python variable into a json code that makes a discord embed.

The problem is that each product of this page give me 3 different texts. How can I save each one in diferents variables. I put my code here
`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/')

product_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="release-calendar"]/div/div[1]/div')
print(product_1.text)
```

The result in terminakl is
119,95€
adidas Originals
Forum MID TM
28 de octubre de 2022, 8:00
Recordármelo

Thanks for the help I really dont know how to save the .text info into differents python varaibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the text in a variable or a

```py
element_text = product_1.text
element_text_split = element_text.split()  # split by space
```

If you wanted the price of that item: `element_text_split[0]` would get the first word

Second word `element_text_split[1]` is the company

You could also slice up the string using [string slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp). Keep in mind not all data you get is going to look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past but that's assuming you have a specific element attribute which you're trying to extract:

For example:

```
element_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="release-calendar"]/div/div[1]/div').get_attribute('title')
```

You'll need to replace `'title'` with the specific attribute from your element which contains the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to get texts of each product on the page, right?
If so, you can use `find_elements()` method to put all the products on the page into a list. For that you need to use an xpath (or any other locator) that finds not one element but all of them.
Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/')

# This finds all products on the page and puts them into a list of elements:
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="auWjdQ rj7dfC Hjm2Cs _8NW8Ug xJbu_q"]')

# This will put text of each product into a list
texts = []
for product in products:
    texts.append(product.text)

# Here we can see what is in the list of texts
print('All texts:', texts)

# If list doesn't suite your needs, you can unpack the list into three variables
# (only if you are sure that there are only three items on the page):
prod1, prod2, prod3 = texts
print('Product 1:', prod1)
print('Product 2:', prod2)
print('Product 3:', prod3)
driver.quit()
```